# SELECT и выборка из другой таблицы

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Довольно простой запрос, только мне ещё нужно получить дополнительное поле `sub_count`, которое берется при помощи `COUNT(*)` из другой таблицы.

Как подставить поле `id` из `table1` в запросе, так чтобы сработала эта выборка `COUNT(*)` из `table2`?

```
$query = "SELECT id, name, url, (SELECT COUNT(*) 
                                   FROM `table2` 
                                  WHERE `otr` like '%;{собственно, сюда нужно передать 
                                                       id из table1, не знаю как};%' 
                                    AND `on_off`!='0') AS `sub_count` 
            FROM `table1` 
           WHERE sub_otr like '%;{$main['id_main']};%' ORDER BY name"
```

Comment: используйте join

Comment: На том месте что вы указали вы можете обращаться прямо по имени колонки `table1.id`. А знаки % к ней приклеивать concat. правда у вас что то со структурой БД не то, раз вы собираетесь id искать с помощью like

Comment: @Mike Спасибо, попробую. БД не моя, довольно старая и переделывать её структуру уже нет возможности.
Поэтому приходится так изощряться.

Comment: @Mike сделал так CONCAT('%;',table2.id,';%'). Всё работает, благодарю.

Comment: тогда более правильно будет `concat(';',otr,';') like CONCAT('%;',table2.id,';%')` потому что ваш текущий вариант может не видеть id находящиеся в начале или конце строки (если там в БД нет точек с запятой)

Comment: Псевдоним не помогает? `FROM table1 as t1` и подставлять `t1.id`. Вроде, в мускуле сквозная видимость псевдонимов...

Comment: @Есть, у каждого id вначале и в конце есть точка с запятой. Но спасибо, буду знать.

Comment: @DNS псевдоним для таблицы не пробовал использовать. Буду знать, спасибо.